# include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Bolts BFCancellationToken'

Tags: xcode, swift, parsing

I just downloaded the Parse sample project, installed LiveQueries pod and nothing else. When I try to build it, it pops the two errors below.. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: add your codes please

Comment: @IvanBarayev I haven't written any code yet... I just downloaded the pods and tried building it...

Comment: Just in case you missed it: http://parse.com/migration

Comment: @EricD If you are referring to the "have to be in a self-hosted MongoDB to use LiveQueries", I have already migrated.. ;)

Comment: @SotirisKaniras I was referring to `I just downloaded the Parse sample project` and I was afraid you were just beginning with Parse. :)

Comment: @EricD Hahahaha!! No no... I started a while ago... :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES

AND

Select the `BFCancellationToken.h` file in the project navigator. In the target membership area on the right there side of xcode there will be a drop down menu next to the target. Select "public" there (default will be "project").

Comment: Try cleaning both the project and the build folder and try again

Comment: Fixed with https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX/pull/50

Answer (score 0):

If you have project in objective-c add use_frameworks! to your pod file at start

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue and found it just resolved by using

`gem install cocoapods --pre`

Which give me `cocoapods 1.1.0.beta.1.`

I'm very happy!!

I also did a

`rm -rf Pods TargetName.xcworkspace Podfile.lock` after quitting xcode and then rerunning `pod install`

Comment: I did that and now I'm facing the below errors:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9467442/17254633/3c587a68-55be-11e6-8acd-7a7c2acbb384.png

Comment: Please get the latest version of ParseLiveServer, I fixed it with pull request #50

You might need to add this to your podfile: 

`pod 'ParseLiveQuery', :git => 'https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX.git'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it removing `Modules` folder from the framework.

- Browse to your framework location which is present in the App Project using finder
- Go inside `Test.framework` folder (In the above case it will be `'Bolts.framework`) & Delete `Modules` folder.
- Clean and Re Build the app, it will solve the problem.